# Multiply each element in numpy array by each element in another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([6,7,8])
```

where the a is generally a 1D array of length `m` and b is a 1D array of length `n` where `n!=m`. I'd like to multiply a and b together elementwise such that the end result is of shape `(n*m, 1)`:

```
result = np.array([6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 7, 14, 31, 28, 35, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40])
```

Comment: Those aren't n-by-1 or m-by-1. Those are 1-dimensional arrays, with no second axis at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for multiplication after extending `b` to a 2D array shape with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis). Then, flatten the multiplication  result with [`.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for the desired output, like so -

```
(b[:,None]*a).ravel()
```

This is in effect performing outer product, so one can also use [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) like so  -

```
np.outer(b,a).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [822]: a
Out[822]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [823]: b
Out[823]: array([6, 7, 8])

In [824]: (b[:,None]*a).ravel()
Out[824]: array([ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40])

In [825]: np.outer(b,a).ravel()
Out[825]: array([ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30,  7, 14, 21, 28, 35,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40])
```